# How to access IBOutlet in UITableViewController Class if the IBOutlet is in UIViewController Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

```
 class AClass: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var mapKitView: MKMapView!

        }

    class BClass: UITableViewController {

    var localAClass=AClass()
    localAClass.mapKitView.mapType=MKMapType.standard 

    }
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You linked the IBOutlet ?

Comment: Yes of course i linked it

Comment: Does **AClass** have access to an object of **BClass** or vice-versa? In your block of code, you are actually creating a new instance of **AClass**, which would probably be different from your expectation of accessing from an already existing instance of **AClass**.

Answer (score 0):

In ClassB, you need to use `UIStoryboard instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` to have IBOutlets instantiated.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController("AClassIdentifier") as! 
AClass
```

And then still, IBOutlets views aren't instantiated until viewDidLoad() for that class. Your `ClassA` would need a second property such as `mapType`, and `ClassB` sets that property instead of directly on the view. Then in `ClassA viewDidLoad` you can set the actual mapView based on this stored property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am not sure what is the "AViewController" in my case, it looks like an id, but where can i find it?

Comment: Updated my answer to be a little clearer. The string "AClassIdentifier" is defined on the storyboard in the Identity Inspector (3rd Tab) under Identity  > Storyboard ID

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AClassID") as! AClass

Comment: And i am having the same Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Updated my answer